# call jquery dialog in gridview label mouseover

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

How can I fire jQuery dialog from ASP.NET gridview label by mouse hover?
I tried this but it doesn't work:

**ASP Markup**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvMain2" runat="server">
   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <table class="tg-table-plain" style="width:100%">
             <tr>
                 <td><asp:Label ID="GRID_LBL" class="GRID_LBL" 
                      runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Some_text") %>'></asp:Label>
                 </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        }
    });

    $("#GRID_LBL").hover(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you add the ASP code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `GRID_LBL` is not the ID of the label in the generated code because ASP.NET generates its own IDs. And since this label is inside a GridView, setting `ClientIDMode` or writing the `ClientID` in Javascript won't work here. You should use a class instead of an ID, classes are the same in the generated code:

```
<asp:Label ID="GRID_LBL" CssClass="GRID_LBL_CLASS"
                      runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Some_text") %>'></asp:Label>

   $(".GRID_LBL_CLASS").hover(function () {
       $("#dialog").dialog("open");
   });
```

Comment: You are Jedi of the Jedi, thanks, it worked...
BUT one more question: I have different values in each Grid row Label, they won't duplicate or there in opened dialog will be duplicates like data from previous row or something like that? Thanks!

Comment: @ASPFox That shouldn't happen. You are only setting the hover method in each datagrid row. But try it out

Comment: Now I can't figure out how to get that Label values in that dialog to check out! Maybe you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If that label exists in each row of the gridview then you can't give all of them the same ID  and you need to set the CSSclass of ASP:label in Column template to something like "GridLabel" then in jQuery code you will attach the hover effect to all labels by their class like this

```
$(".GridLabel").hover(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have added the script below to your head

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

hope you have only one Gridview label with id  `GRID_LBL`

here is the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/HAjYX/)

Comment: I tried that but it works only when its not in Grid but I need it to call from grid :(

Comment: it will work only if there is only one element with id ="GRID_LBL"

Comment: yes I have only one element with id ="GRID_LBL"
Maybe he needs to be found in grid, maybe jquery don't see that label?